# C# versiones MVC en VisualStudio

Tags: c#, vb.net, asp.net-mvc

Trabajo actualmente con VisualStudio 2017, C# y he trabajado con plantillas de ASP 4.5.2 como se muestra en la imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Soy programador web y no tengo mucho conocimiento sobre estas herramientas de Microsoft, me he acostumbrado a trabajar con VisualStudio 2017 y la versión de MVC que se ve en la imagen.
¿Alguien puede explicarme la diferencia de trabajar con una versión anterior como VisualStudio 2008, puedo trabajar con MVC de la misma manera? ¿Que versión de MVC sería en este caso? Cualquier explicación básica me sirve para entender estas diferencias, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las versiones se diferencian más que nada en las facilidades que te ofrecen para escribir menos código. Por ejemplo, en versiones más recientes te pueden proporcionar `Helpers` adicionales a los de la versión 3.

[Aquí podrás encontrar las diferencias entre versiones de MVC](http://www.webdevelopmenthelp.net/2014/02/asp-net-mvc3-vs-mvc4-vs-mvc5.html).

Una diferencia entre las versiones del Visual Studio es que el compilador puede trabajar con versiones del lenguaje C# más recientes que te permiten también escribir menos código, un ejemplo sería el operador lambda

```
public string NombreCompleto
{
    get
    {
        return string.Concat(Nombre, " ", Apellido, " ", Apellido2);
    }
}
```

puede ser reducido a

```
public string NombreCompleto => string.Concat(Nombre, " ", Apellido, " ", Apellido2);
```

[Aquí puedes ver las diferencias en las versiones del lenguaje C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/).

Comment: Justo lo que buscaba, gracias

Comment: @WalterCordova modifiqué un poco la respuesta para que quede mejor ordenado, pero me alegra que te aclare la duda!

Comment: en conclusión, si vería la diferencia de regresar a una versión como VisualStudio 2008 cierto

Comment: VS2008 tiene un compilador antiguo y soporta una versión anterior del lenguaje. Creo que puedes instalarle las nuevas versiones, pero VS2017 también corrige errore y añade herramientas útiles.

Comment: VS2008 es demasiado antiguo.